# onload input focus error Cannot find component for expression "input1" referenced from "j_idt12"

Tags: jsf, input, onload, autofocus

the follow code is on a JSF header.xhtml template.  the page that loads is home.xhtml which has the header.xhtml template reference from the main template and is included using ui:composition template="header.xhtml"
note:  the home.xhtml has no code except the ui:composition

below is the code on the template header.xhtml

```
                    <form id="headerForm" name="frmSearch" method="get"
                    action="search.xhtml">
                    Search <input id="input1" type="text" a:required="true"
                        name="keyword" value="#{param['keyword']}" a:autofocus="true" />
                    <p:focus for="input1"/>                         
                    <f:param name="keyword" value="#{param['keyword']}" />
                </form>
```

Comment: a plain html form is wrong in JSF, use an `h:form` and leave out the method attribute

Comment: as btw is a plain `input` without any jsf attributes on it... (or did your default namespace change? And please create a [mcve]